# Show current week/date on Excel Project Timeline

Tags: excel, project-management, conditional-formatting

I have Excel based Project Planner which I am working on.
[image: It looks like that]

It is downloaded from some free templates and I am modyfying it to get it fit to our needs.

I need to show somehow - border, pattern overlay etc. - current week.
It is not an issue for me to get current week number,
but I have no idea how to find this week in this table and how to highlight it.

Can anybody help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put the Days as a full date, i.e. 2015-08-04, =E3+7, ... and put a custom format that's just dd for the range.

Then you can put a conditional formatting in the row/range based on the formula:

```
=AND(TODAY() >= E$3, TODAY() <= E$3+6)
```

Assuming E3 is the field hat currently houses 04 under Aug.

Comment: Thank you. Succeed.

FORMULA: =AND(TODAY() >=H$3, TODAY() <= H$3+7)
APPLY TO: =$H$2:$AAA$555

Maybe someone will use it in the future.
Thank you for help.

Answer (score 0):

Solved based on Robin suggestion.

FORMULA: =AND(TODAY() >=H$3, TODAY() <= H$3+7)
APPLY TO: =$H$2:$AAA$555

Maybe someone will use it in the future.
Thank you for help.